# Immediate-window-like command prompt?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

Does anyone know if there exist some kind of immediate-window-like command prompt, either to run from inside VS or as a separate program. It would be nice to have something like that to try and evaluate static methods etc without having to debug the solution (for example, evaluate Path methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/) a lot; a somewhat-lightweight editor that gives you a runnable console app that you can test expressions in. Very useful for trying out stack overflow answers before posting them =)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the Direct-Window? You can directly evaluate Methods and Functions in there (though, he does have to compile the assemblies before that).

Alternatively you can use [C# Script](http://www.csscript.net/).

Comment: Where do I find the Direct-Window?

Comment: You should find it in the menu, Debug -> Window -> Direct.

Comment: In my version of visual studio it's called the 'Immediate' Window

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell (v2) for this:

```
PS> Add-Type -Path .\my_assembly.dll
PS> [MyAssembly.MyClass]::SomeStaticMethod(...)
```